# image is complaining fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, image, imageview

I have a master/detail app, where I need to get the image from the master and put it in the detail

It's complaining on the imageView line although I have a file called Gerbera.png image but it won't show.  Also how do I call the image from the master to the detail page?

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var btnCall: UIButton!

func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.



    if let detail: AnyObject = detailItem {

        if let myWebview = webView {

            let stringRepresentation = MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString?.joined(separator:"")

            print ("urlString", MasterViewController.MyVariables.urlString)
            print ("sR",stringRepresentation)

            let url = NSURL(string: stringRepresentation as! String)
            let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)

            myWebview.scalesPageToFit = true
            myWebview.loadRequest(request)
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named:"Gerbera.png")!
```

}
    }

Answer (score 0):

Please try this line

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named:"Gerbera")!
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this.  My Detail View shows image on the top then web view on the bottom.  I realized that the detail view should show code for the image first before code for the web view.  So I put it under viewDidLoad() and it worked!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     imageView1.image = MasterViewController.MyVariables.flowerImage!.first
```